# LoadLibraryW() failing to load DLL in System32

Tags: c++, dll, loadlibrary, system32

I'm trying to load a DLL that was installed with a printer driver in the C:\Windows\System32\ folder with the following code:

```
LoadLibraryW(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\MagAPI.dll");
```

`GetLastError()` is reporting that "The specified module could not be found". If I move the DLL outside of the System32 folder (C:\SomeFolder\MagAPI.dll for example) then it will load fine so it doesn't seem like it's a problem with the DLL itself. Is there some weird Windows security feature that might be blocking my application from loading it? That's the only thing I can think of but I can't find any definitive answers.

Here's the debug output from ShowSnaps, which shows where it's failing:

```
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrLoadDll - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Windows\system32\MagAPI.dll DLL path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;<otherstuff>
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrpLoadDll - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Windows\system32\MagAPI.dll DLL path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;<otherstuff>
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrpLoadDll - INFO: Loading DLL C:\Windows\system32\MagAPI.dll from path C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;<otherstuff>
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Windows\system32\MagAPI.dll DLL path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;<otherstuff>
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrpSearchPath - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Windows\system32\MagAPI.dll DLL path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;<otherstuff>
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrpResolveFileName - ENTER: DLL name: C:\Windows\system32\MagAPI.dll
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrpResolveFileName - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrpSearchPath - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrpFindOrMapDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrpLoadDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
1a8c:1fd4 @ 19006756 - LdrLoadDll - RETURN: Status: 0xc0000135
```

Comment: What version of Windows are you on? You may need admin rights to see the contents of System32. Quick test you can do is right click and run your application as admin (win vista and above I think) and if it works then that's the issue.

Comment: @JesusRamos I've already confirmed that the DLL is in that folder at that exact path, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No I'm asking you to confirm whether it's a permissions issue or not. Accessing System32 sometimes from code requires admin rights on the running application even just to read a file.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the issue. I just tried running the application as admin and it's still failing the exact same way. I'm on Windows 7 64-bit btw. It's a 32-bit application though.

Comment: When you move the file "out" of system32, where do you move it *to*? Is it possible that library has import-dependencies that are satisfied when its in the folder where it loads correctly, and not satisfied when residing in system32. Can you do a dependency walk on it (with `depends.exe`, for example, from MS) and see what might be missing. Its a possibility, but judging by your ShowSnaps output, the file name itself is simply not resolving. How odd.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter where I move it to as long as it's just not in System32. When testing I moved it to a folder all on it's own at C:\SomeFolder\MagAPI.dll and pointed LoadLibrary() to that path and it works fine. `depends.exe` also says it's all fine.

I've also sent an email to the developers of the DLL to see if they might know of anything weird that could be causing this. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mention that your application is 32-bit, the DLL that you're loading must also be 32-bit.

The likely reason `LoadLibrary()` is failing is that you're running a 64-bit edition of Windows, but your printer driver has erroneously installed its 32-bit DLL in question into the `System32` folder instead of the `SysWOW64` folder.

Some background: On 64-bit editions of Windows, 64-bit DLLs go in `System32` folder, and 32-bit DLLs go in the `SysWOW64` folder. I know it sounds like it should be the other way around, but don't let the names confuse you; the folders are named like that are for backward-compatibility reasons. The `SysWOW64` folder is supposed to be transparent to applications: Windows has a feature called file-system redirection that makes it possible for 32-bit applications to load 32-bit DLLs by specifying the `System32` folder (just as they always have) even though the DLLs are actually inside `SysWOW64`.

On the other hand, `LoadLibrary()` will simply refuse to load a DLL that's been placed inside the wrong folder. This is the behavior you're probably seeing.

The real solution to your problem is to contact the printer manufacturer and inform them that their driver installer is putting its DLLs into the wrong folder under 64-bit editions of Windows. If they ever fix this, your application will start working correctly without any changes to your existing code.

In the meantime, you should be able to work around your problem by doing this:

1. Before you attempt to load the DLL, copy the DLL from `%windir%\Sysnative` to some known folder that you have control over. (I suggest that you create a uniquely named folder inside `%TEMP%` and copy the DLL into that folder). Note: `Sysnative` is a special alias that maps to the native system folder, which is `System32` under 64-bit editions of Windows.
2. Call `LoadLibrary()` and pass it the path of the copy of the DLL that you made in step 1.
3. When you're done using the DLL, unload it and delete the copy you made in step 1.

The above workaround might not work if you need to support 64-bit Windows XP, since the `Sysnative` alias is documented to work only on Windows Vista or later. An alternative workaround is to manually bypass file-system redirection:

1. Temporarily disable file-system redirection by calling `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()`. This will allow your application to see what's *really* in `System32`.
2. Copy the DLL from `System32` to some known folder that you have control over.
3. Reenable file-system redirection by calling `Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection()`.
4. Call `LoadLibrary()` and pass it the path of the copy of the DLL that you made in step 2.
5. When you're done using the DLL, unload it and delete the copy you made in step 2.

Note that if you're thinking of calling `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()` to get `LoadLibrary()` to work without having to copy the DLL, don't bother: `LoadLibrary()` doesn't pay attention to that setting. (I actually tested it.)

More information: [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately for me, `LoadLibraryW` (in a 32-bit process) still returns 0 when I point it to a copy of `shell32.dll` copied to my desktop folder (from `SysWow64`). The exception message "The specified module could not be found" is maddening because it simply isn't true, gah.